# Committed change to github not being recognized when doing git status on local clone?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm trying to make sure that my local clone is in sync with the repository on GitHub.

Another user committed a change to the GitHub repository and on my local clone I'm doing a: `git status` - which tells me `"Your branch is up-to-date with "origin/master"`
- this of course not being true since I know there's a change to the GitHub repository.

Prior to this, I've done nothing more than a: `git clone https://github.com/user/reponame.git`

I'm probably missing some steps before doing `git status`?

*Disclaimer: Im totally new to Git.*

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to verify that your local clone is in sync with the repository on GitHub ,
you can use `git remote -v` to show your current remote. You will get something like this,

```
$ git remote -v
# Verify the remote
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
```

Make sure `origin` is set appropriately.

A possible reason could be that you are on different branches of the same repository. You are on the `master` branch now, and the commit is on some branch other than `master`.

You can use `git branch -a` to show all branches in your local clone, and check if there have other branches. Of course you can do a `git pull` first to get the latest commits.

Hope this helps.